# mod_rewrite url with query string i18n

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
<ul>
   <a href="?lang=pt"><li class="pt lang"></li></a>
   <a href="?lang=en"><li class="us lang"></li></a>
</ul>
```

If I have an url like this:

```
http://mywebsite/site/?lang=en
```

With a pure mod_rewrite solution, how can I transcribe to this format?

```
http://mywebsite/en/site/ Or http://mywebsite/site/en/
```

I am trying this, but apparently is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/?$ ?lang=$1
```

More details: I am using this class to generate i18n tokens.

https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n

---

*This class tries to find out the user language by generating a queue of the following things:*

```
    Forced language (if set)
    GET parameter 'lang' ($_GET['lang'])
    SESSION parameter 'lang' ($_SESSION['lang'])
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE (can be multiple languages) ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
    Fallback language
```

---

**Basically, what I want is a friendly url but using this class.**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*)\?lang=([a-z]{2})
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This convert a request uri from `/site/en` into `/site/?lang=en`

```
RewriteRule ^(/[^/]+/?)(.*) $1?lang=$2 [L,QSA]
```

if you want have first the language you could try:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*) /$2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This convert a request uri from `/en/site...` into `/site.../?lang=en`

I have tried these rewrites within a vhost with apache 2.2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName www.test.org

  DocumentRoot /var/web/
  <Directory /var/web/>
      Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.test.org_error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.test.org_access.log combined

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteLogLevel 8  # set to 0 in production
  RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/www.test.org_rewrite.log

  RewriteRule ^(/[^/]+/?)(.*) $1?lang=$2 [L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

And within rewrite.log i see:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /site/en
(3) applying pattern '^(/[^/]+/?)(.*)' to uri '/site/en'
(2) rewrite '/site/en' -> '/site/?lang=en'
```

Please also pay attention rewrite log: never enable it in production environment.

Comment: sorry, but no. the url stays with ?lang=

Comment: apparently not, also the issue is not so simple, because of the php class. I will define the language at start and ignore the problem. thanks.